# Creating a textBox Programatically and referring to it

Tags: c#

I have a multi functional app so i create a textbox with for loop functions.

```
TextBox logtextbox = new TextBox();
logtextbox.Name = "textBox1_" + stringval[0]; //string.Format("logThread{0}", i);
```

I want to use this textbox outside the for loop function in a thread. The thread will already have the stringval value with it. I need to know a way to refer to it so i can add text to it.

Comment: Is this for webforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)

{

TextBox logtextbox = new TextBox();
logtextbox.Name = "textBox1_" + stringval[0];
this.Controls.Add(logtextbox);
}

TextBox mytextbox = ((TextBox) this.Controls.Find("logtextbox",true)[0]); 

EDIT
mytextbox.text = "blah";
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have something like this?

```
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    TextBox logtextbox = new TextBox();
    logtextbox.Name = "textBox1_" + stringval[0];
}
```

Store the created TextBox's in a collection.

```
List<TextBox> CreatedTextBoxList = new List<TextBox>();
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    TextBox logtextbox = new TextBox();
    logtextbox.Name = "textBox1_" + stringval[0];
    CreatedTextBoxList.Add(logtextbox);            
}
```

Then you can loop through `CreatedTextBoxList`

```
foreach(TextBox tb in CreatedTextBoxList)
{
    //do something with tb
}
```

or use Linq to get a specific TextBox.

```
TextBox tb=CreatedTextBoxList.Where(x => x.Name=="NAMEOFTEXTBOXHERE").FirstOrDefault();
tb.Text="Hello, world!";
```

Comment: instead of a list you could also add it to a control collection

Comment: Thanks. But can i edit the text in textbox of specific textbox. Like, textbox_anything.text = "ss";

Comment: @user3502927 Yes, use Linq to get a reference to the specific TextBox and then set the text of it.

Comment: I am  not sure on how to use it, can you show me a example.

Comment: @user3502927 I added an example at the bottom for how to do that with Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtBasicTextBox = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
 txtBasicTextBox.ID = "txtBasicTextBox";



System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txtBasicTextBox = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)form1.FindControl("txtBasicTextBox");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume this is WinForms

```
var stringval = new List<string>{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.Name = "textBox1_" + stringval[i];
    textBox.Text = "YOUR OLD VALUE";
    Controls.Add(textBox);
}

var searchTextBox = Controls["textBox1_" + stringval[1]] as TextBox;

if (searchTextBox != null)
{
    searchTextBox.Text = "YOUR NEW VALUE";
}
```